# Servlet mapping for a basic rest api?

Tags: servlets

I'm trying to write a web app that needs to expose some methods that I'm going to use with ajax. I can make one servlet to route all incoming requests, or I can make multiple servlets, one for each request type. Something like:

```
public class ServletMain extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws IOException 
    {
        // parse the path and figure out which service call was made.
    }
}

// web.xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SerlvetMain</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/a</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/foo/b</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/foo/c</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or:

```
public class ServletA extends HttpServlet;
public class ServletB extends HttpServlet;
public class ServletC extends HttpServlet;

// web.xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SerlvetA</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/a</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SerlvetB</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/b</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SerlvetC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/c</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

just wondering if we can do whatever we want, or if there's some rule to how to structure this kind of stuff?

Thanks

Comment: If you have the flexibility, it's a lot nicer to use a library like [RESTlet](http://www.restlet.org/) instead of having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really intend to do this with "plain vanilla" Servlet API instead of a more suited REST API like [JAX-RS](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/index.html) (i.e, [JSR311](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/) with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) as reference implementation), then I recommend to go for the Front Controller pattern as depicted in your first example. That's more nicely abstracted than a `web.xml` polluted with all possible `url-pattern` entries.

Basically, just have a single Servlet which intercepts on all requests, grabs the pathinfo by [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) and determine the desired action accordingly based on a combination of the request method and pathinfo.

At least, try to look how *they* did it with Jersey (with the holy annotations!) and try to do the same. Or, better, just don't reinvent the wheel and use it ;)